# Why html loaded to another html file with jquery does not appear correctly?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried to separate the top bar of a webpage into another HTML file. I was able to load the HTML file into a div in the main web page with jQuery 'load' function, but the problem is that it doesn't appear correctly. When I put all the code in the same HTML file, it looked as I expected. I made a div to have `calc(100% - N px)`, and it shows correctly in the main HTML. But loaded HTML from the separate file does not fit to the div width, despite I set the body style `width: 100%`. It only appears like a much smaller box within the div.
For now, I don't see any mistake that I made on the code.

HTML - index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryjs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
    <div class = "TopBar" id = "TopBar"></div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

HTML - topbar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body style = "margin: 0px; height: 54px; width: 100%; background-color: #dddddd;">
        <span class="helper"></span><h2>Drive</h2>
        <button class="TopBarBtn"><img src="assets/icon_sort.png"> Name </button>
        <button class="TopBarBtn"><img src="assets/icon_newFolder.png"> New Folder </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.TopBar{
    position: fixed;
    width: calc(100% - 251px);
    height: 54px;
    top: 138px;
    left: 251px;
    z-index: 5;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#TopBar").load('topbar.html');
});
```

Comment: Don't use <html>, <head>, <body>, <link>, etc. in topbar.html since you already load this in your index.html, load all in index.html

Comment: Your background color is too long; you have six e and one s; the max is seven characters for hex colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [check the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/) you will find the following information:

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.

The document then goes on to explain:

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved
>   document and insert it into the current document. During this process,
>   browsers often filter elements from the document such as ,
>   , or  elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by
>   .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved
>   directly by the browser.

So, first, you need to contain the elements you want rendered from within your `topbar.html` within an element with an ID, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body style = "margin: 0px; height: 54px; width: 100%; background-color: #dddddd;">
      <div id="topbarContainer">
        <span class="helper"></span><h2>Drive</h2>
        <button class="TopBarBtn"><img src="assets/icon_sort.png"> Name </button>
        <button class="TopBarBtn"><img src="assets/icon_newFolder.png"> New Folder </button>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The following example is taken from the documentation I referenced earlier:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

You could modify this example to fit your jQuery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#TopBar").load('topbar.html #topbarContainer');
    $("#TopBar").children().css("width", "100%");
});
```

Then, your HTML should be rendered as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryjs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
    <div class = "TopBar" id = "TopBar">
      <div id="topbarContainer">
        <span class="helper"></span><h2>Drive</h2>
        <button class="TopBarBtn"><img src="assets/icon_sort.png"> Name </button>
        <button class="TopBarBtn"><img src="assets/icon_newFolder.png"> New Folder </button>
      </div>
    </div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

You might still need to modify your CSS styles to compensate for changes here. What styles have you assigned to the `.helper` and `.TopBarBtn` classes?

If the `load()` function is not the issue, as mentioned in your comment in another answer, then perhaps it is simply an issue with your CSS.

If the problem persists, please include a copy of the rendered HTML (can be copy & pasted from your web browser's code inspector) and the rest of your CSS so that it can be properly debugged.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your comment helped me solving the problem. The problem was that when the "topbar.html" is loaded in "index.html", it set the #topbarContainer's width not to be 100% of #TopBar element in "index.html". I think in order of executing functions, it first set the width of #topbarContainer not refering to property of #TopBar and loaded the container.
So I could fix it by adding new function after the load function as follow:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#TopBar").children().css("width", "100%");
});

Comment: But still I'm not sure it's the best way to solve the problem. For example, it seems that I have to put another function to adjust #topbarContainer's width as window's width changes.

Comment: @JaeeulBae I have updated my answer to include the solution you mention in your comments. You needn't wait for the document to be ready twice. You should be able to just write it directly beneath the `.load()` function as shown.

Comment: If this does not work then perhaps you'd need a callback. Let me know and I'll write a fiddle to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load a full html template inside another html page. I suggest you use iframe in this scenario. But still if you want to load the content of `topbar` I would suggest the following code changes.

```
<div style = "margin: 0px; height: 54px; width: 100%; background-color: #dddddd;">
<span class="helper"></span><h2>Drive</h2>
<button class="TopBarBtn"><img src="assets/icon_sort.png"> Name </button>
<button class="TopBarBtn"><img src="assets/icon_newFolder.png"> New Folder </button>
</div>
```

And remove all html and body tags from topbar.html file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm just trying not to use iframe in this example. I've tried remove all the html and body tags in the topbar.html file but it still didn't work as I intended. Is there any mistake remaining in the code?